# property set does not exist on type storage

Tags: ionic2

```
import {Storage} from  '@ionic/storage';
constructor(storage: Storage){}
   this.storage.ready().then(() => {
   // set a key/value
   this.storage.set('name', 'Max');

   // Or to get a key/value pair
   this.storage.get('age').then((val) => {
     console.log('Your age is', val);
   })
 });
```

this gave me an error: Property 'ready' does not exist on type storage,

any help guys

Comment: is it property ready or set?

Comment: all throws the same error type, ready, set, get flag as property not set on the storage instance, meaning it is non existent@suraj